# How to update custom field in jira 7+ using java

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Answers to this question are outdated or incomplete on all the sources that I checked.

Here are some examples:

[Delete issue in JIRA using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949582/delete-issue-in-jira-using-java)

[How do I save a value into a custom field in JIRA programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251892/how-do-i-save-a-value-into-a-custom-field-in-jira-programmatically)

[JIRA creating issue using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140544/jira-creating-issue-using-java)

[Automating custom field value change in JIRA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568693/automating-custom-field-value-change-in-jira)

[Jira: How to obtain the previous value for a custom field in a custom IssueEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571825/jira-how-to-obtain-the-previous-value-for-a-custom-field-in-a-custom-issueevent)

[CustomFieldManager is not getting the custom field after modifying the custom field name using REST api in jira](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131879/customfieldmanager-is-not-getting-the-custom-field-after-modifying-the-custom-fi)

I don't have enough reputation to comment on any of theese questions. But I have an answer.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: It's answer to 6 questions. All answers to them are outdated in 2017 and didn't help me. I don't have 10 reputation so i decided to write my answer as a question. What else should I do if can't just leave a comment anywhere?

Comment: So best thing to do is ask a question and answer it yourself. in the question mention the earlier questions are outdated and the answers not working anymore.

Comment: I feel like schizophrenic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my resolution:

```
CustomField csUserField = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObjectByName(fieldName);
IssueService issueService = ComponentAccessor.getIssueService();
IssueInputParameters issueInputParameters = issueService.newIssueInputParameters();
issueInputParameters.addCustomFieldValue(csUserField.getId(), value_string);
issueInputParameters.setSkipScreenCheck(true);
issueInputParameters.setRetainExistingValuesWhenParameterNotProvided(true, true);
UpdateValidationResult updateValidationResult = issueService.validateUpdate(user, issue.getId(), issueInputParameters);  
if (updateValidationResult.isValid())
{
    IssueResult updateResult = issueService.update(user, updateValidationResult);
    if (!updateResult.isValid())
    {
        log.warn("ISSUE has NOT been updated. Errors: {}\n", updateResult.getErrorCollection().toString());
    }
    else
    {
        log.warn("ISSUE has been updated.\n");
    }
}
else
{
    log.warn("ISSUE has NOT been updated. Errors: {}\n", updateResult.getErrorCollection().toString());
}
```